# Image serving from the high performance blobstore without direct access to get_serving_url()

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers, jinja2

I'm converting my site over to using the blobstore for image serving and am having a problem.  I have a page with a large number of images being rendered dynamically (through jinja), and the only data available are entity keys that point to image objects that contain the relevant serving url.

Previously each image had a url along the lines of `"/show-image?key={{image_key}}"`, which points to a request handler along the lines of this:

```
def get(self):
  imageInfo = db.get(self.request.args.get("key"))
  imagedata = imageInfo.data // the image is stored as a blob in the normal datastore
  response = Response()
  response.data = imagedata
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = imageInfo.type
  return response
```

My question is:  How can I modify this so that, rather than returning a response with `imageInfo.data`, I return a response with `imageInfo.saved_serving_url` (generated from `get_serving_url` when the image object was created).  More importantly, is this even a good idea?  It seems like converting the `saved_serving_url` back into data (eg using `urllib.fetch`) might just counteract the speed and efficiency of using the high-speed datastore in the first place?

Maybe I should just rewrite my code so that the jinja template has direct access to the serving urls of each image.  But ideally I'd like to avoid that due to the amount of parallel lists I'd have to pass about.

Comment: Fetching the URL yourself and returning the contents is going to be way slower than just serving the blob up directly. And serving redirects to the serving URL is likewise going to lose you all the benefit of using the image serving API. Using the image serving URLs directly is the only way to gain the improvements that API provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not returning the serving url instead of the imagedata?

```
<img src="/show-image?key={{image_key}}" />

def get(self):
  imageInfo = db.get(self.request.args.get("key"))
  return imageInfo.saved_serving_url
```

Comment: That would be ideal but it doesn't seem to work, nor does returning the url as a self.redirect().  Feels like there should be a way to do this, though...

Comment: what does not work? do you get an error? does it not return the serving_url?

Comment: The images just fail to load - the page's sourcecode shows them with the src "/show-key?key=blahblah" but as far as i know simply returning a url won't cause the image to load.  Bare in mind these are embedded images that I'm retrieving from within the img-tag, not an ajax request or something that is replacing the full image src url.

Having said that my knowledge of http responses is not great, so maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: indeed - the images fail to load either way

Comment: 30-40 thumbnails.  Just to note, on a separate page a similar number of images are shown and load successfully with get_serving_urls passed directly to the jinja template, so my problem is just with rendering images by pointing image sources at a request handler (rather than having the complete image urls passed to the template directly)

Comment: not sure if you can actually call instance or classmethods within a jinja template but that would be a good solution.

Comment: Sending redirects should work, but will negate the performance improvements of the image serving API.